# XML Lint parse XML

Tags: xml, shell, xmllint

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Environment xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oe="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1" xmlns:ve="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovfenv" oe:id="" ve:vCenterId="">
  <PlatformSection>
    <Kind>VMware ESXi</Kind>
    <Version>7.0.0</Version>
    <Vendor>VMware, Inc.</Vendor>
    <Locale>en</Locale>
  </PlatformSection>
  <PropertySection>
    <Property oe:key="test" oe:value="test123"/>
    <Property oe:key="testing" oe:value="testing123"/>
  </PropertySection>
  <ve:EthernetAdapterSection>
    <ve:Adapter ve:mac="" ve:network="" ve:unitNumber="7"/>
  </ve:EthernetAdapterSection>
</Environment>
```

I want to parse it using XMLLint and fetch all  "oe:key" and "oe:value"

I tried following commands:

1. xmllint --xpath "string(//PlatformSection)" file1.xml
2. xmllint --xpath "string(//Environment)" file1.xml

But both are returning blank. Similarly, I tried for Property and PropertySection and getting a blank response.

Comment: What did you try to do? What is not working?

Comment: You're searching in the default namespace, but your data is in `http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1`.

Answer (score 1):

The input XML contains namespaces. All elements are bound to the following namespace: `xmlns:oe="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/environment/1"`

Please try the following XPath:

```
/oe:Environment/oe:PlatformSection
```

Or

```
/oe:Environment/oe:PropertySection/oe:Property/@oe:key
```

Or try namespace wildcard approach

```
/*[local-name()='Environment']/*[local-name()='PlatformSection']
```

To get first `oe:key` attribute

```
/*[local-name()='Environment']/*[local-name()='PropertySection']/*[local-name()='Property'][1]/@oe:key
```

To get all attributes

```
/*[local-name()='Environment']/*[local-name()='PropertySection']/*[local-name()='Property'][1]/@*
```

One more approach is outlined here: [xmllint for XML Namspace](https://chihungchan.blogspot.com/2011/01/xmllint-for-xml-namspace.html)

Comment: I am getting below error:

XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
XPath evaluation failure

Comment: I am able to fetch Section but how to fetch oe:key and oe:value.

Tried  xmllint --xpath "/*[local-name()='Environment']/*[local-name()='PropertySection']/*[local-name()='Property']/@oe:key", but getting incorrect response

Comment: @kushagramittal, I added it to the answer how to get the first **oe:key** attribute.

Comment: xmllint --xpath "/*[local-name()='Environment']/*[local-name()='PropertySection']/*[local-name()='Property'][1]" file1.xml

This works but now one below

xmllint --xpath "/*[local-name()='Environment']/*[local-name()='PropertySection']/*[local-name()='Property'][1]/@oe.key" file1.xml